# How to encrypt and encode using crypto-js library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, hash, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt the string using secret key with the help of crypto-js, there are two issues one its always generating same key which is not expected it shoud be unique eveytime , and second issue is the size of the encrypted key is longer than expected i am trying to print this format and size `GwJPNUfPXZZsuc0iqOFhn%2BYhMJKxXBUYl9g3iKqL8CE%3D` this always contain 2 percent special character in it.

trying encrpt with sha256 and do the encoding and return the above pattern any help ?

```
index.js 

const CCrypto = require('crypto-js');

function encryptSHA256(data, secretKey) {
    const secretKeyWordArray = CCrypto.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey);
    return CCrypto.AES.encrypt(data, secretKeyWordArray, {
        mode: CCrypto.mode.CBC,
        padding: CCrypto.pad.Pkcs7,
        iv: CCrypto.lib.WordArray.create([0]),
    }).toString();
}

function generateEncryptedValue(paymentId, specialtyID, secretKey) {
    const concatString = paymentId.toString() + "_" + specialtyID;
    const encryptedResult = encryptSHA256(concatString, secretKey);
    const base64Result = CCrypto.enc.Base64.stringify(CCrypto.enc.Utf8.parse(encryptedResult));
    const percentEncodedResult = encodeURIComponent(base64Result);
    return percentEncodedResult;
}

// Example usage
const paymentId = 15680298; // paymentId is a number
const specialtyID = '8018290';
const secretKey = "EiD0BVQle0xFjZvYOupQsXCWAcAwBaTjlZ7G7rryNos=";
const result = generateEncryptedValue(paymentId, specialtyID, secretKey);
console.log('Encrypted and Percent Encoded Result:', result);
```

JAVA code which is in legacy app we are moving to Nodejs:

```
<paymentMethodId>
                                                                  
                                                                   <xsl:value-of select="xsutil:encryptSha256(concat(string(paymentMethodId),'_',$patientIdentifier))"/>
                </paymentMethodId>

here parameter is concatenated string which is (paymentMehtodId_specialtyID) there is some inbuilt function is being used beyond this.

<func:function name="xsutil:encryptSha256">
      <xsl:param name="parameter"/>
      <func:result select="dp:encode(dp:encrypt-string('http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc',$secrerKey,$parameter),'url')"/>
    </func:function>
```

Comment: You describe that your current implementation behaves differently than expected without defining with sufficient precision what you actually expect. In the comment of the answer you refer to a legacy Java code that you might want to port. If so, you should edit your question and post the Java code there so that it is clear how the NodeJS implementation should work.

Comment: The code has a number of vulnerabilities (most notably, it is not AES compliant due to an encoding issue in conjunction with a CryptoJS bug). Regarding the first point (if I understand it correctly): A ciphertext that changes with each encryption using a fixed key can be achieved with a random IV for each encryption. However, suggestions for bugfixes probably make no sense as long as it is not clear whether the code works functionally correctly at all.

Comment: @Topaco i agree what you suggested and i have added the java code , unfortunately we have to move same logic what we have in Java to Nodejs thats why asking for help

Comment: The posted XML configuration does not reveal the details of the encryption. Can you post a source code, a library or a specification that makes the logic used by `encryptSha256()` transparent? In general, but especially in the case of an incomplete description, (non-productive) complete test data would be helpful. For the data currently posted (`paymentId`, `specialtyID`, `secretKey`), the ciphertext *generated with the Java reference code* is missing. Such test data can be used to verify a supposed logic. Hence add the ciphertext generated with the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

1. Constant Secret Key: You're using a constant secret key (secretKey) for encryption. To generate a unique key each time, you need to either generate a random key or use a different key-generation mechanism.
2. Base64 Encoding: You're encoding the encrypted result in Base64 twice (once when encrypting and once when converting to UTF-8). You should only perform the Base64 encoding once.

Updated code fix example below:

```
const CCrypto = require('crypto-js');

function generateSecretKey() {
  const keySize = 32; // 256 bits
  return CCrypto.lib.WordArray.random(keySize).toString();
}

function encryptSHA256(data, secretKey) {
    const secretKeyWordArray = CCrypto.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey);
    const encrypted = CCrypto.AES.encrypt(data, secretKeyWordArray, {
        mode: CCrypto.mode.CBC,
        padding: CCrypto.pad.Pkcs7,
        iv: CCrypto.lib.WordArray.create([0]),
    });
    
    return encrypted.toString();
}

function generateEncryptedValue(paymentId, specialtyID, secretKey) {
    const concatString = paymentId.toString() + "_" + specialtyID;
    const encryptedResult = encryptSHA256(concatString, secretKey);
    const percentEncodedResult = encodeURIComponent(encryptedResult);
    return percentEncodedResult;
}


const paymentId = 15680298; 
const specialtyID = '8018290';
const secretKey = generateSecretKey(); 
const result = generateEncryptedValue(paymentId, specialtyID, secretKey);
console.log('Encrypted and Percent Encoded Result:', result);
```

Comment: thanks for the response i am moving code from our legacy java code to nodejs and there they are using the same generic secret key to generate unique keys, also when i pass different values like `paymentId :1384220 and 
specialtyID: '8089205'` then its generating shorten size key any idea why