# Using crypto module getting unknown cipher?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

trying to encrypt aes-256 using cipher but it is throwing error unknown cipher any idea what is missing in below code.

index.js

```
   function paymenIdEncryption(specialtyID,paymentId) {
            const convertToString = `${paymentId}_${specialtyID}`;
            const secret_key = "EiE0BVQle0xFjZvYOupKjHJKAcAwBaTjlZ7G7rryNos=";
            const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    
            const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbs', Buffer.from(secret_key, 'base64'), iv);
            let encrypted = cipher.update(Buffer.from(convertToString, 'utf-8'));
            encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);

            const encryptedData = {
          iv: iv.toString('base64'),
          encrypted: encodeURIComponent(encrypted),
      }

    return encryptedData;;
        }
    
    console.log(paymenIdEncryption(13780298 ,"8018928"))
```

Error:

```
'Error: Unknown cipher\n    at Cipheriv.createCipherBase (node:internal/crypto/cipher:116:19)\n    at Cipheriv.createCipherWithIV (node:internal/crypto/cipher:135:3)\n    at new Cipheriv (node:internal/crypto/cipher:243:3)\n    at Object.createCipheriv (node:crypto:138:10)\n
```

Comment: There is no CBS mode, presumably you mean CBC i.e. `aes-256-cbc`, s. [*Block cipher mode of operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

Comment: @Topaco thanks for pointing out it fixes my intial problem my expected encryption size is this "GwJPNUfPXZZsuc0iqOFhn%2BYhMJKxXBUGl9g3iKqL8CE%3D' but it is retruning "pMFokZz7eD3BJbsPK2qGsQ%3D%3D" with above code when i add addtional extra space or specialty character in convertToString variable then it prints this "sawsytz%2Fm8jP0Cwsla6UzSmQ1T5Qy1SbI3qL4SWQ2aM%3D" which is closer to what i expect but why we need to pass extra comma or space to produce this result tryign to understand if you can help

Comment: As I tried to explain in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77715153/9014097): Without knowing the reference logic you are trying to mimic, we can only guess. If you can't post the reference code (nor a link to the library nor documentation), why can't you at least generate *complete* test data with the Java code and post it?

Comment: The posted code returns a 32 bytes ciphertext, which equals Base64 and URL encoded the length you expect: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/T0T. The shorter ciphertext can actually only be produced with a plaintext that is smaller than 16 bytes.

Comment: @Topaco this should also return the the same size (paymenIdEncryption(1384220 ,"8089105"))

Comment: Concatenation of both data with a `_` as separator results in a 15 byte plaintext and a 16 byte ciphertext, not a 32 byte ciphertext. Seems that your logic does not work.

Comment: @Topace this is how Java is concatenating `<xsl:value-of select="xsutil:encryptSha256(concat(string(paymentMethodId),'_',$patientIdentifier))"` i am trying to do the same i hope comma is not counted

Comment: Sorry, this discussion makes no sense unless you can provide further information such as the requested test data. Due to the many possibilities of encryption (padding, encoding, key derivation, etc.), this is just guesswork with little chance of success.

Answer (score 0):

Typo. To [list all available ciphers](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptogetciphers):

> const {   getCiphers, } = require('node:crypto');
>
> console.log(getCiphers()); // ['aes-128-cbc', 'aes-128-ccm', ...]